# Add rows in a loop with a condition

Tags: r

So, I have a tibble:

```
a <- 1
b <- 1
c <- 1
df <- tibble(a,b,c)
```

I would like to add n rows where 5 is added to df$a in each row, while the other columns stay the same value. So if n=1, the resulting tibble would ideally look like this:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
      a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1
2     6     1     1
```

Would be great if you could help me out! For example with a for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## update

If you want to do the same thing on both `a` and `b`, you can try

```
n <- 3
df %>%
    mutate(across(a:b, ~ list((0:n) * 5 + .x[1]))) %>%
    unnest(c(a, b))
```

which gives

```
      a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1
2     6     6     1
3    11    11     1
4    16    16     1
```

---

I hope this is what you are after, for example

```
n <- 3
df %>%
    mutate(a = list((0:n) * 5 + a[1])) %>%
    unnest(a)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
      a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1
2     6     1     1
3    11     1     1
4    16     1     1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas. How could I change the mutate expression so that df$b simultaneously also gets +5 in n rows? Just like df$a?

Comment: You're my hero Thomas!

Answer (score 2):

In base R as an alternative, you could try the following. This will essentially add n rows to your data.frame (where your data.frame may contain more than one row to begin with). The rows added would fill with the last row of your data.frame, except we would modify the selected row `a` and increase by 5 `n` times.

```
n <- 3
rbind(df, transform(df[rep(nrow(df), n),], 
                    a = a + seq(n) * 5))
```

**Output**

```
      a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1
2     6     1     1
3    11     1     1
4    16     1     1
```